# Using Font Awesome dynamically in Swift

Tags: swift, font-awesome

I am trying to dynamically encode font-awesome characters in Swift. I am using an API which returns the code for the character (in the format f236) and I want to inject this as unicode into a UILabel. Ideally I would like to do the following:

```
var iconCode: String? = jsonItem.valueForKey("icon") as? String
var unicodeIcon = "\u{\(iconCode)}"
label.text = "\(unicodeIcon) \(titleText)"
```

However you obviously can't do this. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@abdullah has a good solution, but here's more about the root problem in case someone runs into it again...

You can't write things like `var unicodeIcon = "\u{\(iconCode)}"` because of the order that Swift parses string escape codes in. `\u{xxxx}` is already one escape code, and you're trying to embed another escape code (string interpolation) within that — the parser can handle only one at a time.

Instead, you need a more direct way to construct a `String` (actually, a `Character`, since you have only one) from a hexadecimal Unicode scalar value. Here's how to do that (with the scalar value as an integer):

```
let unicodeIcon = Character(UnicodeScalar(0x1f4a9))
label.text = "\(unicodeIcon) \(titleText)"
```

Of course, your character code is in a string, so you'll need to parse an integer out of that string before you can pass it to the above. Here's a quick extension on `UInt32` for that:

```
extension UInt32 {
    init?(hexString: String) {
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexString)
        var hexInt = UInt32.min
        let success = scanner.scanHexInt(&hexInt)
        if success {
            self = hexInt
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let unicodeIcon = Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(hexString: "1f4a9")!))
label.text = "\(unicodeIcon) \(titleText)"
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's exactly what I needed! I was considering using Thi's FontAwesome helper class but for what I needed to do it just seemed like overkill. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Its been a long days later, @rickster or anyone would you tell me, what could be the Objective C equivalent of "Character(UnicodeScalar(UInt32(hexString: "1f4a9")"

Answer (score 3):

Convert the iconHex string to a decimal, then the decimal to a UnicodeScaler, then to a character. Finally use string interpolation to get the result:

```
let iconStringHex = "f236"
let iconDecimal = Int(iconStringHex, radix: 16)!

let unicodeIcon = Character(UnicodeScalar(iconDecimal)!)
label.text = "\(unicodeIcon)"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting icon code as "fa-xxxx" then you could do this:

```
var iconCode = //Code from json...
label.text = "\(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(iconCode)) \(titleText)"
```

I assume you have this method fontAwesomeIconWithName() in extension from font awesome and label.font is set as FontAwesome.

Comment: Here's a link to that extension: [thii / FontAwesome.swift @ GitHub](https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift).

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import FontAwesome_swift

class FontAwesomeConverter {
    public static func image(fromChar iconCode: String,
                         color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.textColor = color
    label.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20, style: .solid)

    let iconDecimal = Int(iconCode, radix: 16)!
    let unicodeIcon = Character(UnicodeScalar(iconDecimal)!)
    label.text = "\(unicodeIcon)"
    label.sizeToFit()

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: label.frame.size)
    let image = renderer.image(actions: { context in
        label.layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
    })
    return image
   }
 }

extension UILabel {
// MARK:  set center alignment
   public func setFontAwesomeIcon(fromChar iconCode: String,
                        color: UIColor) {
    self.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 30, style: .solid)
    self.textColor = color

    let iconDecimal = Int(iconCode, radix: 16)!
    let unicodeIcon = Character(UnicodeScalar(iconDecimal)!)
    self.text = "\(unicodeIcon)"
    self.sizeToFit()
  }
}
```

## USSAGE:

//For ImageView Image

```
imageView_MainMenu.image = FontAwesomeConverter.image(fromChar: "f085", color: .white)
```

//For Label

```
label_MainMenu.setFontAwesomeIcon(fromChar: "f085", color: .white)
```