# FontAwesome icon displayed as question mark

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, font-awesome

I am trying to set the button text for the following :

[image]

The first step I followed is to include the font file in the project. I then referred it in the Info.plist.
I copied the icon from the [**cheatsheet**](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io) :

[image]

Then I set the font for the button in IB as follows :

[image]

As a result, I get a question mark on the button (both in IB and on running).

[image]

---

---

[image]

**Just for cross checking, I set some other icon instead of this. It worked fine.**

[image]

---

---

[image]

---

---

[image]

Where could the mistake be ?

Comment: Try setting the button title in code instead of in the IB Attributes inspector?

Comment: @matt : Thanks. I tried doing [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306722/using-font-awesome-dynamically-in-swift) way, but still getting question mark.

Comment: @matt : I tried replacing it by envelope icon as I did in IB. It worked fine. Is it possible that anything might be wrong with the icon code ?

Comment: Certainly it’s possible.

Comment: @matt : I hope there is a way to report this.

Comment: @matt : Reported the bug : https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/13636

Comment: I think you should delete your report. You were using the wrong font.

Comment: @matt : issue closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong font. The one you want is FontAwesome5FreeSolid (`fa-solid-900.ttf`).

This works fine on my machine:

```
    let s = "\u{f362} Convert"
    let ss = NSAttributedString(string: s, attributes: 
        [.font : UIFont(name:"FontAwesome5FreeSolid", size:17)!])
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 200, height: 200)
    b.setAttributedTitle(ss, for: .normal)
    self.view.addSubview(b)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Also make sure you have the same font file name in info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

In IB set only the font name and size , in code use something like this

```
self.backBu.setTitle(String(format:"%C",0xf053), for: .normal);
```

replace `f053` with unicode that you want , also make sure that target memberShip is checked for the font resource and you add it to info.plist

Comment: I tried 
self.buttonConvert.setTitle(String(format:"%C Convert","f362"), for: .normal)

Result : Some different icon.

Comment: checked the membership and added to info plist

Comment: Firstly, it is there. Secondly, if it was not, other icon wouldn't have worked.

Comment: I am afraid, I got the same output. "? Convert"